# Create a button to interact with Upload Photo on WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, vb.net

I'm trying to create a button to click Upload Photo on WebBrowser Control.
This is the HTML document:

```
  <a id="post_two_image_upload" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_image_upload" title="Upload Image" aria-labelledby="post_two_image_upload_voice" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" href="javascript:;" role="button" tabindex="-1">

  <span class="mceIcon mce_image_upload"></span>
  <span id="post_two_image_upload_voice" class="mceVoiceLabel mceIconOnly" style="display: none;">Upload Image</span>
```

and this is my code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("post_two_image_upload").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

The error I get is: `System.NullReferenceException - {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Can anyone explain me how can I get this button to work, please?

Comment: You can't call methods or properties on null values (except extension methods), and that chain there has plenty of possible nulls.

Answer (score 0):

If `WebBrowser3` is null, has a null Document, or said document has no element matching the id `"post_two_image_upload"`, or the element found has no `"click"` to invoke, you will indeed get a `NullReferenceException`.

You should place a breakpoint on that line and see if one of the first two is the case. If not, split the statement into separate lines and save each call to a variable. You should be able to find the null fairly quickly.